# Why does this request return a 403?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I'm gathering images to train a ML program, and to do so, I have made the following function. It works for every single server I've tested so far, except for one :

```
exports.grabResize = function(name,url,skip) {
    var options = {
      jar: true,
      maxRedirects: 5,
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36'
      },
      timeout: 15000,
      url:url
    };


    var file = fs.createWriteStream(name);
    var transformer = sharp().resize(579,null).withoutEnlargement().jpeg()
    .on('error',function(err){console.log(err);return(true);});
      request(url).on('error', function(err) {
          return(true);
      }).on('response', function (res) {
        var encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
        console.log(res.headers);
        if (encoding == 'gzip') {
          res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(transformer).pipe(file);
        } else if (encoding == 'deflate') {
          res.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(transformer).pipe(file);
        } else {
          res.pipe(transformer).pipe(file);
        }
      });

    file.on('finish', function() {
        file.close();
    });
};
```

The only server that returns a 403 is the following : "http://g.nordstromimage.com/imagegallery/store/product/Large/13/_9503953.jpg"

Is it just an IP ban thing, or is there more to it? I must say that I'm using an AWS instance to gather my images, so maybe some other 54.xxx ip has done nasty things before me. I've of course changed IP a few times to check, to no avail.

I've rarely found an url I couldn't scrape, let alone a simple image. I've tried all sorts of headers, and every failure got me more curious, have I missed something?

Here's the reply :

```
{ server: 'AkamaiGHost',
  'mime-version': '1.0',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  'content-length': '345',
  expires: 'Mon, 15 Dec 2014 07:02:08 GMT',
  date: 'Mon, 15 Dec 2014 07:02:08 GMT',
  connection: 'close' 
}
```

I'm not looking for how to circumvent this, but more to why it happens, and what kind of information the server bases its decision upon.